# Nodemon automatically crashed [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nodemon

nodemon automatically disconnects nearly after 30 sec after starts and gives this error "[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...". if I make some changes in the file then it will automatically get restarted and if the file is kept idle without doing any change nodemon gets crashed nearly after 30 sec and server gives no response but after crash if I make some changes then it will automatically again get restarted same thing continues after restart also

Full Error

```
D:\react\inotebook\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (D:\react\inotebook\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (D:\react\inotebook\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:767:11) {       
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 15938834,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (D:\react\inotebook\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:370:20)  
            at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\react\inotebook\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:293:22)      
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)    
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017    
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }   
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

Node.js v18.16.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

My directory schema

```
React 
|__inotebook
   |__backend
   |  |__node_modules (folder)
   |  |__index.js
   |  |__db.js
   |  |__package-lock.json
   |  |__package.json
   |
   |___ Files and folders created by "npx create-react-app"
```

db.js code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017"

const connectToMongo=()=>{
    mongoose.connect(mongoURI)
    console.log("Connection Successful")
}
 
module.exports=connectToMongo
```

index.js code

```
const connectToMongo=require('./db')
connectToMongo()
```

I have tried uninstalling full mongoDB and installed it again. I have installed nodemon by -> npm i -D nodemon and tried it by this also npm install -g nodemon

my package.json code

```
{
  "name": "inotebook-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "iNoteboot - Your notebook on the cloud",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
}
```

Comment: Read the error message: `MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017`, Your connection to mongodb does not work.Is the server running? Is it listen on IPv6 IP? Try "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" in your connection string/host. This error was a million of times already here.

Comment: Now giving me this MongoRuntimeError: Unable to parse localhost:127.0.0.1 with URL....

Comment: Read my comment again: `Try "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost"`. What should `e localhost:127.0.0.1` be? Thats a invalid connection URL. -> `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`

Comment: Yes, it's working but why it's not working on localhost? I was struggling from last 8 hours

Comment: Because `localhost` resolves since a couple of newer versions in node to the IPv6 loopback address instead of the IPv4. When you Database server does not listen on the loopback IPv6 address, then its not working. You MongoDB Server listens/is bound only the the IPv4 loopback address/interface.

Comment: Ok, Anyways thanks a lot you have saved my time again thanku very much